# Can not install pgadmin4 in ubuntu based distribution

Tags: postgresql

Seems there is an issue while installing pgadmin4 for postgress db. I tried to follow [these](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Apt) instructions but at the end I get

> Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt focal-pgdg InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'

Does anybody know what is the issue ?

I am using Pop Os 20.04

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu expects repositories to have all architectures by default. As there are no packages for i386 this results in the error you're seeing.

To fix this, you have to tell apt which architectures to expect, so your `pgdg.list` should look like this:

```
deb [arch=amd64] http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt NAME-pgdg main
```

`NAME` would be the output of `lsb_release -cs`.

Note 2020-05-05: Judging from your distro name, it's based on Ubuntu 20.04. There are no pgAdmin4-packages for focal yet. Installing from the eoan repo fails because of missing libpython3.7 :(

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit your pgdg.list file in `/etc/apt/sources.list`
there is a line in the file thats says : `deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ focal-pgdg main`
change it to `deb [arch=amd64] http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ focal-pgdg main` save the file and all you have to do now is a :  `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`